# CI/CD process with Jenkins or Chef

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, continuous-integration, chef-infra, continuous-deployment

Suppose I have to do the following jobs:
1: Detect there is a new WAR file on S3.
2: Pull it from S3 bucket.
3: Stop the Wildfly Server
4: Replace the WAR file on Wildfly Server
5: Restart the Wildfly Server
[image]

The diagram is using Jenkins as an example. The Wildfly and Appeon are on an EC2 Instance. Because of some licensing issue, we can't use CFT to create a new instance every time, so I have to assume all these steps be done within this EC2 Instance.

Let's assume the failover is not an issue.

Two routes to get this done, one is using Jenkins, like Jenkins will watch the S3 bucket, and stop, replace, restart the server and WAR, without creating a new instance every time.

The other is using Chef on that Instance, it will check the S3 bucket every 5 minutes, for example, if there is a new WAR file, pull it down. (Suppose the WAR file name doesn't change...), using some magic script to stop the server, replace the WAR file, restart the server, all run on the same Instance.

Since I don't know CI/CD, Jenkins, or Chef.

So any advice or example would be much help! Thanks in advance!

Comment: > We have Plugin for Wildfly Plugin 'https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/WildFly+Deployer+Plugin' like we have for Tomcat, you can configure there your Wildfly configurations. >> but i am thinking for Local Repo checking, we have configuration for Git Repository for checking whether change has occur or not. >>

Comment: I have some doubts
1) If War is deployed in Tomcat first it will stop the server and undeploy and redeploy the new war.. Is this process different in WildFly??                                          
2)How you are able to generate the WAR file?(code you are using maven/ant)
3)why do you need chef here?

Comment: @ChandraSekhar  1)  I don't know either Tomcat nor Wildfly, but I assume it's the same. 2) I will generate the WAR file in another EC2 Instance using PowerBuilder + Appeon and upload to S3. 3) I want to start from S3 bucket uploaded to redeploy, automatically doing all the following steps.

Comment: This is, at best, opinion based and so not a good question for StackOverflow by its own rules :-/ Might want to cross-post to the DevOps stackexchange if this gets closed.

Answer (score 1):

If this is really all you're doing, Chef would be waaaaaay overkill. A simple bash script run from cron (or a systemd timer unit if you want to be super fancy) would probably be fine. I would start small and try to not overcomplicate things, the more moving pieces in a deployment pipeline, the more things can potentially break (usually at the very worst time).

Comment: But how to start the script that does the magic, when it detects the object on S3 bucket get overwritten or there is a newly created object.

Comment: Probably just a cron job.

Answer (score 1):

How about watching the process that uploads the war file, instead of watching an s3 bucket. Set the deployment as downstream to the upload process. Then your stopping service and deploying can be a bunch of shell scripts via jenkins. It should just stop ur service , may be use ssh for it. Ssh and do curl/wget of the new war(by deleting the old war) & ssh to start the service... you don't to make things complex by involving chef into it.